# How to enable external access to the Virtual machine on private link?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, bridge, qemu, tap

I would like to benchmark virtual networking of KVM-QEMU. For this purpose, I connect two servers (server 1, and server 2) with one wire. I use server 1 to run the QEMU VM and I want to access this VM from server 2.
Here's the overview of the configuration.

```
           o ens5f0    (ip 192.168.11.12/24)
           |
           | (server 2)
 ------------------------- (Host/Network boundary)
           "
           "
 ------------------------- (Host/Network boundary)
           | (server 1)
           |
           o ens5f0 
           |
           o br0.      (ip 192.168.11.11/24)
           |
 ------------------------- (VM/Host boundary)
           | (guest)
           |
           o (enp0s2) inside VM
             (ip 192.168.11.77/24 (from dhcp))
```

I followed the documentation [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU#Tap_networking_with_QEMU). I configure a bridge on server 1 and add interface `ens5f0` to it.

```
server 1
---------------------
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set ens5f0 master br0
ip addr flush dev ens5f0
ip addr add 192.168.11.11/24 dev br0
ip link set dev br0 up
dnsmasq --interface=br0 --bind-interfaces --dhcp-range=192.168.11.12,192.168.11.254
ip link set dev ens5f0 up
```

Then I launch QEMU using the following command.

```
server 1
---------------------
qemu-system-x86_64 \                                                                                                         
   -initrd initrd.img-5.4.0-84-generic \                                                                                     
   -kernel vmlinuz-5.4.0-84-generic \                                                                                        
   -nographic -monitor none -serial stdio\                                                                                   
   -append 'root=/dev/vda1 console=ttyS0' \                                                                                  
   -machine q35 -cpu host \                                                                                                  
   -drive "file=${disk_img_snapshot},format=qcow2,if=virtio" \                                                               
   -nic bridge,br=br0,model=virtio-net-pci \                                                                                 
   -enable-kvm \                                                                                                             
   -m 2G \                                                                                                                  
   -smp 4 \                                                                                                                 
;
```

Inside the VM, interface `enp0s2` gets ip address `192.168.11.77/24`.

```
VM
--------------------
~$ sudo ip addr show enp0s2
2: enp0s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000                                  
    link/ether 52:54:00:12:34:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.77/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s2                                                 
       valid_lft 3531sec preferred_lft 3531sec
```

The `ping` command has access to this ip address from server 1 and the ip address 192.168.11.11 is also accessable from the VM.

On the second server, I configure the IP address to be static and equal to 192.168.11.12/24.

```
server 2
------------------------
$ ip addr add 192.168.11.12/24 dev ens5f0

$ ping 192.168.11.11
PING 192.168.11.11 (192.168.11.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.11.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.327 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.11.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms
```

The issue is that ip address 192.168.11.77 could not be reached from server 2 and the VM cannot ping server 2. How could could I enable external access to the VM on this link?

Answer (score 0):

You can run  tcpdump -i br0 in order to see whats on the route.

Comment: A bit more explanation of how this answers the question would improve the answer